# Access Vue code from an outside Node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue application with Vue-Router. Let's say that I export the `router` from `main.ts` file within the project.

I want to create a node.js script that can get the `router` export to perform some analysis over it without the Vue application running.

The analysis consist on recursively go through all the component tree that a certain route requires to then generate a report (API used in the component / Route of the component / Shared within X routes... )

How could I achieve this?

I have tried importing the built files (so `require('../dist/js/main...')`) but this fails.
I also tried with `ts-node` and importing that file but it struggles to resolve `*.vue` files.

Comment: Consider explaining your case further, there may be workarounds. "some analysis over it" - what analysis exactly?  It's not a good idea to import from dist for a usual browser app because this results in trying to init in Node environment

Comment: can't you declare your routes in a `.ts` file and use it in your `vue router` as well as the separate script?

Comment: @Kaneki21 I suppose the problem here is that for usual router definitions there are component imports

Comment: @EstusFlask . My analysis requires to get all the routes to be able to aggregate the Vue Component tree under certain routes in that vue router to afterwards generate a report. Would this make sense?

Comment: yes, the `.ts` file has to designed in a particular format so that they can be used in both places, `lazy loading component` can also be a way. But again this are workarounds in my opinion.

Comment: @SirPeople Depends on the purpose. What's the use for this report, is it for convenience only? I suppose you can build a separate entry point as that doesn't bootstrap the app but exports route definitions and then import it in Node. Or possibly define the routes in a way that will make it easier to consume. As for comp lazy loading, this is certainly a way but you may have TS-related problems because `component: () => import('...vue')` doesn't exist in Node and TS will complain on it

Comment: Can't you just define routes in a separate file using string paths instead of imports, then analyse it where it needs to be analyzed and for router part just throw it into a function that will resolve imports from the string paths? Or wouldn't that work in webpack?